# Proving 3-Hitting Set is NP complete

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Consider the following desicion problem:
3-Hitting Set - This problem is indentical to the classic Hitting Set problem with the following constraint: Each set has to be exactly 3 items long. Similarly to 3-SAT and SAT, It seems almost obvious that 3-Hitting Set is also NP-complete like the original Hitting Set problem. Is it possible to reduce the original Hitting Set problem to the 3-Hitting Set problem directly, or we must go through a third NP-complete problem?

Comment: Have you tried constructing such a reduction? For example, by emulating the reduction from SAT to 3SAT?

Comment: There is a very simple reduction from 3SAT, by the way.

Comment: In the SAT to 3-SAT reduction, we spilt the formula and connect the parts using a variable and it's negation. The analog in the HS to 3-HS reduction I can think of is: every time we spilt a set, we can increment the k parameter, where k is the size of the required HS. But I'm not sure this move won't effect the reduction correctness.